# Returning the results as a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

If I make a for-loop and return all the values in some vector in `matlab` as follows:

```
function elements(v)
for i=1:length(v)
    c(i) = v(i)
end
```

When I run the following, I get the results as shown:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4]

A =

     1     2     3     4

>> elements(A)

c =

     1


c =

     1     2


c =

     1     2     3


c =

     1     2     3     4
```

How can I return the results as: `c = [1 2 3 4]` only?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, maybe I miss your point, but can't you simply call 'c=v(:)'?

Answer (score 1):

```
function elements(v)
for i=1:length(v)
    c(i) = v(i);
end

disp(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is gonna be what you really mean, but I'd this:

```
function c = so_test(v)
 c = v(:)';
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An even more compact solution

```
function c = elements(v)
for i=1:length(v)
    c(i) = v(i);
end
```

Note that it does not look much different from the other solutions,
But I think that this is the what you want to do assuming you want to do something complicated/dependant on c.

If you just want all elements, just use `v(:)'`, `v` or `v'` instead like @fpe mentioned.